# Hibernate JPA, Spring MVC and LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-mvc

When trying to get items from db, I got this error:

```
13:00:13.876 [7838526@qtp-204712603-0] ERROR o.h.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: bo.myobj, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.myob.linkedstuff, no session or session was closed
```

I understand that with switching to eager instead of lazy loading solves this problem, e.g.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "myobj", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

and I also understand that eager loading is discouraged. What is the best practitce in order to cope with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better separation between the persistence and other layers. Make sure the objects produced by the persistence layer do not include any reference to Hibernate.

The article [Hibernate, Get Out of My POJO!](http://www.mojavelinux.com/blog/archives/2006/06/hibernate_get_out_of_my_pojo/) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess that is the right strategy. However, I have been running into so many issues since I have started using an ORM that I wonder if there is any benifit using *any* ORM ... sorry, just *had* to mention that :-(

Comment: @erlord: Feel free to not use an ORM (at least not one with a defined persistence context) then :) And good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure this occurs when there is no active transaction.

Read the spring reference part about [Declarative Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative)

Usually it boils down to your service method or class needing the `@Transactional` annotation if you use annotations or otherwise proper xml configuration of `<tx:advice>`.

Comment: Sorry, I have checked all beans - @Transactional is present in all DAO methods ... my xml looks fine too

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. What I meant is: are you still inside the transactional scope, when you access the collection? Because that's probably not happening inside a dao method, is it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem, usually caused by rendering the view after the hibernate `Session` is closed. A common solution is to use the [Open Session In View](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView) pattern, which will keep the hibernate session open for the lifetime of the web request.

Spring comes with a [filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) that implements this pattern. To enable it for all JSP files in your application, for example, add something like this to your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>osivFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>osivFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I inserted the lines, however, the laziiniterror persists :-(